# maze collision in corona

Tags: coronasdk

I am planning to create a maze game. I have no idea how can I create the maze. The first thing I do is to make a 1 png file for the maze. I would like to ask if it is possible to create just 1 image for the maze or do I need to create the maze by arranging its block one by one? [image]

Comment: I am also trying this. Had u success to do so? I just posted same issue over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451464/unable-to-move-object-between-blank-spaces-in-lua-corona. Please help u u had done this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using some kind of text format for building the maze. The most convenient way of declaring mazes would be to use lua itself, i.e. by building an array. The next step would be to generate the map to show it to user. I thing it would by a much simpler approach then to work with PNG images.

Your maze example can by divided into rooms with 4 walls/exits facing 4 directions. Have you considered building a two dimensional array of 16 values representing all combination of walls (different rooms) ?